# How to allocate a memory block and place it into Cache?

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory

I want to dynamically allocate a memory block for an array in C/C++, and this array will be accessed at a high frequency. So I want this array to stay **on chip**, i.e., in the **Cache**. How can I do this explicitly with code in C/C++?

Comment: What environment? C and C++ aren't really cache aware in their standard forms.

Comment: You will have to define your hardware and O/S, and any mechanism will be completely O/S specific, and you probably can't do it in the L1 or L2 caches, and you probably wouldn't want to either.  If the memory is truly in use at high frequency, then it will be kept in the cache by its frequent use.  If it isn't in sufficiently frequently used to be kept in cache anyway, then you'd be hurting the overall performance of your system if you managed to find a way to subvert the caches.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard C++ language feature that allows you to do this.

Depending on your compiler and CPU, you may be able to use an arch-specific CPU instruction in an asm block:

```
T* p = new T(...);
size_t n = sizeof(T);
asm {
    "CACHE n bytes at address p"
}
```

...or some builtin compiler function ("intrinsic") that does this.

You will need to consult your CPU manual and/or your compiler manual.

As an example, x86 CPUs have a set of instructions starting with `PREFETCH`.

And another example, GCC has a function called `__builtin_prefetch`.  See [GCC Data Prefetch Support](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html)

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this built-in function :) Now I'm tempted to use it ;)

Answer (score 3):

I will try to answer this question from a bit different perspective. Do you really need to do this. And even if it would be a way to do so, will it worth it? Imagine there is a "magic" void * malloc_and_lock_in_cache( int cacheLevel ) function. What you going to do with this data. If it's an application limited to while (1) loop with random array access from single thread you will have such behaviour anyway due to optimisation and CPU architecture. If you think about more real world solutions you always have logic around access. For example locking for multithreading, certain conditions, etc. The the question - do the rest of your application algorithms are so perfect that only left to do is to allocate array in cache.

Do all other access/sorting/lookup functions are state-of-art logic which cannot be reviewed rather then gaining very limited performance kickback trying to overwrite CPU optimisation.

Also do you consider to run your application without ANY operation system on a raw hardware so you shouldn't care about how your allocation will affects OS behaviour, rest of application running around?

And what should happen if your application will run inside virtual machine or environments like XEN.?

I can remember one similar popular subject 15-18 years ago about physical memory usage  and disk caching utilities. Indeed tools like MS-DOS smartdrive or similar utilities were REALLY useful and speed up things a lot. Usenet was full of 'tuning advices' and performance analyses for things like write-through/write-back settings.

Especially if your DOS application were processing large amounts of data and implemented some memory swapping logic (I am talking about times then 4MB RAM was luxury) that's became mostly a drama, that from one point of view you need as much memory you can, but from another point of view you need swapping, so you actually need to swap, but swapping goes through cache etc..

But what happened next. We've got VM386 mode, disk cache/memory swaps integrated into OS, and who was care anymore about things like tuning smartdrive/ramdisks. In general it was 'cheaper' to allocate as much as you need VM then implement own voodoo algorithms to swap physical memory blocks (although this functionality is still in WinAPI).

So I would really recommend to concentrate efforts on algorithms and application design rather then trying to use some very low level features with really unpredictable results until you dont develop some new microkernel OS.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. First, which cache? L3, L2, L1? You can [prefetch](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/prefetch.html), and [align](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) so it its access is more optimized, and then you can query it periodically maybe to make it stay and not go LRU'd, but you can't really make it stay in cache.

Comment: You're probably right, but is possible the OP is working in an environment that supports locking down either some lines or all of the cache.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I agree, it's just that I thought he meant only C++ or C.

Comment: It depends on your architecture.  For example on some ARM CPUs the "caches" are under manual control, and you specifically allocate/deallocate memory in them with a modified `new` operator.  `T* t = new (fastmem) T();`

Answer (score 1):

First you have to know what's the architecture of the machine you want to run the code on. Then you should check it there's an instruction doing that kind of stuff.

Actually using the memory heavily will force the cache controller to put this region in cache.

And there are three rules of optimizing, you may want to know them first :)
http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RulesOfOptimization